# How to determine what is the current Gabarge Collector mode in .NET 4?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

The .NET Garbage Collector has a couple of modes. I'd like to know what is the default mode for a Windows Server SKU. How to determine what is the current Gabarge Collector mode in .NET 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Niranjan's answer includes more relevant details, but I believe the answer to your actual question is [`System.Runtime.GCSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.aspx).

It includes the properties:

- `IsServerGC` - Indicates whether server garbage collection is enabled.
- `LatencyMode` - Indicates the current latency mode for garbage collection.

Comment: This also works down to the .NET Framework 2.0 (I didn't check earlier versions).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to go through  Chris Lyon's WebLog article  [How To Tell Which GC Mode Your Application Is Using](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clyon/archive/2005/02/04/367419.aspx) and Steven Hollidge's [Garbage Collector .NET 4](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.in/2012/04/garbage-collector-net-4.html).

> Introduced in .NET 4:  Background [and Foreground] (Workstation only)
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework version 4, background garbage
>   collection replaces concurrent garbage collection.

Moreover, for more information you can look these Scott Hanselman's [Using the Server (rather than Workstation) Garbage Collector with the .NET Framework (CLR)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=d45f6073-ea61-416c-ba7e-3c56651ed7a6)  and this one - [Garbage Collection Modes - GCCollectionMode](http://weblogs.asp.net/wallym/archive/2007/04/15/garbage-collection-modes-gccollectionmode.aspx), Chris Lyon's - [Server, Workstation and Concurrent GC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clyon/archive/2004/09/08/226981.aspx)

***Edit:***

> **Que: How to determine what is the current Gabarge Collector mode in
>   .NET 4?**

[System.Environment.IsServerGC](http://lab.msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cpref/html/P_System_Environment_IsServerGC.asp) should be used to check against Server GC, the `System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC` will return true if we’re in server GC mode, and false if in workstation.

> **Que: what is the default mode for a Windows Server SKU.**

[From](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911716)
The **`Microsoft .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) uses the Server garbage collector (GC) on multiprocessor computers.`** This is the default behavior. The Server garbage collector is optimized for scalable throughput on multiprocessor computers. To reduce contention and to improve garbage collector performance on multiprocessor computers, the Server garbage collector creates one heap per processor for parallel collections.

The `Workstation garbage collector` is optimized for `low latency`. Low latency is typically required for client applications. However, low latency may cause decreased throughput after you configure the **`.NET Framework common language runtime to use the Workstation garbage collector.`**

Comment: down voter care to comment.. the `System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC` will return true if we’re in server GC mode, and false if in workstation.  it is good to put explanation link rather copy paster here..